# Eliminate the controller and action in the URL

Tags: grails

I have some pages. One is "Who we are page" (the landing page), there are 3 "register" pages, each of them asking different things, and there is a "Contact" page, with information about the location, the phone, email, etc. So, when user acces, say, second register page, the url says "/controller/action". I want to eliminate the controller part in the URL, and if the action is named "reg3" in the URL it must show "registration3", and so on.

I have read it is achieveable with URLMappings.groovy file, but I don't fully understand how it works. This is my URLMappings.groovy

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }



            "/registro"
             {
                controller = "Registro"
                action = "registro_page"
             }
             "/registro2"
             {
                 controller = "Registro"
                 action = "reg2"
             }

             "/registro3"
             {
                 controller = "Registro"
                 action = "reg3"
             }
             "/contacto"
             {
                 controller = "Registro"
                 action = "contacto"
             }
             "/quienes_somos"
             {
                 controller = "Login"
                 action = "auth"
             }


    }
    "/registro" (controller:'Registro', action:'registro_page')
    "/registro2" (controller:'Registro', action:'reg2')
    "/registro3" (controller:'Registro', action:'reg3')
    "/contacto" (controller:'Registro', action:'contacto')
    "/quienes_somos" (controller:'Registro', action:'home')
    "/"(controller:'redirigir',action:"redirigir")
    "500"(view:'/error')

    "/login/$action"(controller: "login")
    "/logout/$action"(controller: "logout")
}
```

As I said, Im not sure if I know what I'm doing...

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of logic errors, most notably the

```
        "/registro"
         {
            controller = "Registro"
            action = "registro_page"
         }
```

blocks that are *inside* the block belonging to the default `"/$controller/$action?/$id?"` mapping.  You should start by removing those entirely, leaving you with just

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
    "/registro" (controller:'Registro', action:'registro_page')
    "/registro2" (controller:'Registro', action:'reg2')
    "/registro3" (controller:'Registro', action:'reg3')
    "/contacto" (controller:'Registro', action:'contacto')
    "/quienes_somos" (controller:'Registro', action:'home')
    "/"(controller:'redirigir',action:"redirigir")
    "500"(view:'/error')

    "/login/$action"(controller: "login")
    "/logout/$action"(controller: "logout")
}
```

This should now work, at least to get you started.

Comment: If I understood it well, now in my render (view:'xxx') I could put render (view: 'registro') and it should call 'Registro/registro_page'?

Comment: @Fustigador no, the URL mappings don't affect `render`, you still have to use the real controller and view names there.  The point with the URL mappings is that if you do `<g:link controller="registro" action="reg3">` it will generate a link to `/app/registro3`.  One thing that may be confusing Grails is that it expects controller names in URL mappings to start with a lower case letter - the class `RegistroController` corresponds to `controller:"registro"` in URL mappings, and I suggest you change your mappings to follow this convention.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#urlmappings), what you are doing shouldn't be too far off.

the upper part seems wrong to me, the single-line mappings

```
"/registro" (controller:'Registro', action:'registro_page')
```

should be enough.

Then you have to take care of the scaffolded views, they don't know about your custom URL Mappings and still create the "old" links. You have to manually adjust all autogenerated links.